# Separating an unknown amount of coordinates in a list into seperate coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that will let a simulated robot move around a space and go around obstacles in the most efficient way possible. I have a list of obstacles hard coded into the code and I have to separate those points into separate variables, but there can be an unlimited amount of obstacles in the list. Each obstacle will have a row and column number, which is how I am determining how the robot will move.

I have tried to create a list and then taken the length of that list and used that to separate the different coordinates in the list, but since there is supposed to be a random amount of obstacles, the code would have to be changed every time another obstacle is added.

```
obstacles = [(2,3),(3,5),(5,2)]
#list of the obstacle coordinates
length = range(0,len(obstacles))
obs1,obs2,obs3,obs4=[obstacles[i] for i in length]
#Seperation of the coordinates into groups
obsRow,obsCol=obs1
#Seperation into the row and column of the coordinates
```

This function is giving an output, but the output only works when the number of obstacles in the list is equal to the amount of obstacles with the number after them (ex: obs1). I want this function to work no matter how many obstacles are in the list without changing the function.

Comment: why do you want to put each cells of the list into separate variables ? this sounds like bad design.

Comment: I don't necessarily need separate variables but I couldn't think of another way to do it

Comment: Then you need to learn more about how to handle lists, (how to iterate over them, how to access/modify it, etc...). Because no matter what you're trying to solve I'm pretty sure breaking each cell into separate variables is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a potentially infinite number of spaces and obstacles you may want to look into A* pathfinding. It's a way to find the most efficient route without exhaustively trying every possible combination (see. The Travelling Salesman problem).

The following [article](https://medium.com/@nicholas.w.swift/easy-a-star-pathfinding-7e6689c7f7b2) provides an example of how you would solve a similar problem in Python alongside the relevant theory to understand the concepts behind the solution.